# actionbar in android have different behavior for support lib version?

Tags: android-actionbar

I find if in the **build.grade** giving different support lib:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'   
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0',
```

the actionbar have different behavior.

- app icon is not showing up in v22.0.0
- menu is not showing up
  in the overflow menu, while in v20 it will.

In the activity, we have the below code.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```

The behavior of v20.0.0 is what I want.
If I want v22.0.0 have same behavior as v20.0.0, what I should do?

Is this because in android 13, some behaviour on actionbar changed?

Answer (score 0):

You must return true in onCreateOptionsMenu() or the menu won't show. That's why you don't see it because the super method returns false. This has not changed and is well-documented.

Other possible reasons why your menu does not show up:

- Your XML menu resource does not use the package prefix attributes of AppCompat but the "android:" attributes instead.
- You are using a Toolbar in your Layout but you don't register it as main ActionBar.
- A bug in this version of AppCompat (but I doubt it). Latest version at this date is 22.2.0.

Since v21, AppCompat implements the Material design behaviour and in Material design the app icon is not shown by default.

Comment: I have changed/tested the code as following, making the  onCreateOptionsMenu always return true. 
       `@Override  
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);  
          return true;  
       }`
But the behavior is still the same, option menu not showing up in the overflow part in v22, while v20 is OK

Comment: That's odd, can you give more details about your code like the content of the menu file or the Activity you inherit from (should be ActionBarActivity) ?

Comment: MainActivity.java:
`public class MainActivity
        extends ActionBarActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        ...
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
`

Comment: Ok, I would also suggest to avoid version 22.0.0 and use the latest 22.2.0 or the previous stable 21.0.3 instead.

Comment: I edited my answer with more possible reasons. If you decide to add more details please edit your original question.

Comment: I have upload code here, can you take a look: https://github.com/xqian/xqian-test/tree/master/MySunShine

Comment: I just tested your project and I see the overflow menu in the Action Bar (3 dots on the right), with 3 items in it. So what is your issue exactly ?

Comment: thanks for you help. What device you are using? then it must be my devices issue. I am using an xiaomi, I will try to find a nexus device for my development work.

Comment: I tested on a Nexus 5 device and the Nexus 7 emulator. Maybe your Xiaomi phone has a physical menu button ? I noticed the 3 dots sometimes don't appear on old devices with a physical menu button but if you press the physical menu button, the overflow menu properly opens. I also noticed this doesn't happen when you use a Toolbar as ActionBar.